# Specify length of list element as index in lapply

Tags: r, list, lapply

I am using lapply to select elements from vectors in a list, but not all vectors in the list include the same number of elements. I typically use:

```
lapply(some.list,"[[",n)
```

were n is the index of the element in the vectors I am trying to parse out. However, this time my list looks more like this:

```
some.vect <- c("aaa_elem1","aa_elem2","elem3","bb_elem4","ccc_elem5","abc_elem6")
some.list <- strsplit(some.vect,"_")
```

When I use my normal lapply method:

```
lapply(some.list,"[[",2)
```

I get the following error: `Error in FUN(X[[3L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds` as expected, because not all vectors in the list have two elements. What I would like is a way to declare the index in `lapply` as the length of the vector.

I also tried defining a vector of the list vector lengths, and assigning it to index:

```
vect.length <- unlist(lapply(some.list,length))
lapply(some.list,"[[",vect.length)
(Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : attempt to select more than one element)
```

and not assigning an index at all:

```
lapply(some.list,"[[")
(Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : no index specified)
```

Is there a way to select all of the last elements of vectors in a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tail`...

```
lapply(some.list, tail , 1 )
```